# Mono .Net support for async await?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, mono, async-await

I wanted to know if writing a self hosted WebApi project using async await keyword features would be supported in Mono on Linux..

I found this:
on the Mono website on the compability page:
[image]

and then there is some text saying *limited ASP.NET 4.5 async stack.*

So... i'm confused...  what async/await aspect is or isn't supported with Mono 4.5 ?

Comment: I think they mean "classic" ASP.NET "Web Forms". Like (http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/performance-and-caching/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-45 or http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheMagicOfUsingAsynchronousMethodsInASPNET45PlusAnImportantGotcha.aspx

Comment: A better, easier and more reliable way would be to write a prototype.

Comment: Hi @abatishchev - what is the meaning of a prototype in this context? Can you please help me understand this?

Comment: @student: My point was to install Mono (on a Linux box such as Ubuntu) and try your code there.

Comment: @abatishchev Oh yeah! You mean - the best way to learn anything is to **JUST DO IT**. I was understanding prototype as some "coding thing". Thank you man!

Comment: I make pull request for mono https://github.com/mono/mono/pull/3048.
It makes Synchronous execution of asynchronous web api stack.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mono cloned ASP.NET 2 pipeline a long time ago, to support the classic ASP.NET WebForms based on "System.Web" assembly. That model was a sync one due to Microsoft's initial design.

However, later Microsoft added many async features to the pipeline (System.Web) during .NET 4/4.5 time frame, and that's a new design Mono does not yet fully clone. That's probably the meaning behind the paragraph.

I don't think Mono should move ahead with "System.Web" as even Microsoft gives it up in favor of OWIN a while ago, and now ASP.NET 5/DNX.

Update:

Please switch to ASP.NET Core today, as it is simply the best in this field for cross platform web applications.