# mono The view 'Index' or its master was not found

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mono, monodevelop

by this tutorial http://www.davidloo.com/?p=479
I installed monodevelop and created ASP.NET MVC project.
but when I run F5 so I have this output:

```
System.InvalidOperationException
The view 'Index' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
~/Views/Home/Index.aspx
~/Views/Home/Index.ascx
~/Views/Shared/Index.aspx
~/Views/Shared/Index.ascx
~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml
~/Views/Home/Index.vbhtml
~/Views/Shared/Index.cshtml
~/Views/Shared/Index.vbhtml

Description: HTTP 500.Error processing request.

Details: Non-web exception. Exception origin (name of application or object): System.Web.Mvc.



Exception stack trace:
  at System.Web.Mvc.ViewResult.FindView (System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext context) [0x00092] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult (System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext context) [0x00044] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult (System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext controllerContext, System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult actionResult) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker+<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>c__AnonStorey5.<>m__0 () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter (IResultFilter filter, System.Web.Mvc.ResultExecutingContext preContext, System.Func`1 continuation) [0x00025] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Version Information: 4.2.1 (Stable 4.2.1.102/6dd2d0d Thu Nov 12 09:52:44 UTC 2015); ASP.NET Version: 4.0.30319.17020     Powered by Mono

MonoDevelop I have in 6.0 version

And file: Views/Home/Index.cshtml exists

Do you know anybody what can be wrong??
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The described exception happens in mono when your code tries to produce really `async` execution.

Mono does not support the `async` pipeline.

I make pull request for mono [like described in this GitHUB post](https://github.com/mono/mono/pull/3048). It makes synchronous execution of asynchronous web API stack.

It is derived from these SO questions:

- [Mono .Net support for async await?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33026799/1305969)
- [Mono with Owin Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37012143/1305969)
- [404 response appended to webapi response](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34834346/1305969)
- [Mono: The view 'Index' or its master was not found](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34629192/1305969)

Now you may use `async` pipeline with this fix for Mono.

Answer (score 0):

I received the same error. I was compiling on my windows machine but running on Mono in Raspbian. So when I typed it in I should have been paying attention to case.

**I typed "index" instead of "Index" once and chrome would not simply let me retype it to include the capital "I".**

I then change the file name to match just to get passed the error and my page loaded.